# Matlab - f(number) doesn't return a number

Tags: matlab, function, trigonometry, exp

```
syms x;
f=symfun(exp(sin(x)^3)+x^6-2*x^4-x^3-1,x);
```

This is my code in Matlab, the problem is when i'm trying to calculate f(2) for example i'm getting exp(sin(2)^3) + 23 as a result.. why am I not getting a number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you need the [`double`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/double.html) function. Symbolic values will stay symbolic until you convert them to a numerical value:

```
double(f(2))
```

Comment: @Savvas. Glad it worked out for you. Please Google next time. It took me less than two minutes to find the answer despite the fact that I'm unfamiliar with the symbolic toolbox.